# Big gap after footer in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, footer

The page is divided for two parts:

1. Big 100% browser height header
2. Main content and footer

You can see only one of these parts in the browser. I write this code that works fine in Firefox and Chrome:

```
    var $header = $('.mainHeader');
    var $main = $('.main');
    var $footer = $('.mainFooter')
    var $body = $('body');

    $('#tosite').on('click', function(e){
        $body.css({overflow: 'auto'});
        $main.show();
        $footer.show();
        $([$header, $main, $footer]).each(function(n){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.animate({top: -$window.outerHeight()}, 400, 'linear', function(){
                if (n == 0) {
                    $this.hide();
                }
                $this.css({top:0});
                $this.css('position', 'relative');
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $('#back').on('click', function(e){
        $body.css({overflow: 'hidden'});
        $([$header, $main, $footer]).each(function(n){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.css({top: -$window.outerHeight()}).show();
            $this.animate({top: 0}, 400, 'linear', function(){
                if (n > 0) {
                    $this.hide();
                }
            });
        });

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

**But in IE there is a big gap after footer for 100% height of the browser.** It disappears with every window resize. Looks like a IE bug. Is there a solution?

Comment: IE10 and browser modes 7-9 so I think every version.

Answer (score 1):

IE likes to calculate height incorrectly, e.g. it sometimes doesn't like blocks with height set by scripts or blocks with images. As a result, it renders incorrectly. I came across such a problem with a sticky footer: every browser got it right except IE8, 9, 10. They rendered a gap after the footer, which was disappearing after the window was resized.

I couldn't find any css solution for this as there doesn't seem to be an obvious reason for every case, so I just forced re-rendering (which happens when resizing) **after** all scripts have made their moves. One of the ways: set padding-top of the body to 1px in css (or whatever value) and change it to zero (or whatever you need, but not the same) with a script.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I found a solution. I just add `position: absolute` to **body** and now it's OK.